# Site creation week

Tags: feature-request, area-51

A common tactic for promoting an issue is to create an issue day/week, ect. Such as Veteran's Day or Reading Week ect. Perhaps we could utilise this for creating sites. **Site creation should proceed as normal outside of this period**

One of the problems with getting a site created on Area 51 is getting attention. When Area 51 first started, lots of people were interested and visited the site. I would image now that not many people visit the site regularly. By the time a site finally is created, many of the users will have lost their interest.

I propose that each year that area51 have a special site creation period of length a few days to a week. This should be promoted via email and by ads on the StackExchange network. By getting everyone to visit the site at the same time, it will be easier to achieve the critical mass necessary for a community to succeed.

Comment: You can't force anyone to visit it, special time period or not. Consistent ongoing promotion is probably a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We *DO* promote proposal across the network and remind followers to return via email.

When a proposal reaches 50% commitment, we place house ads on all the sites across the network — a constant reminder of what Area 51 is about.  At 60% commitment, we send a brief email to followers and committers who may have drifted off… just to let them know the proposal has made significant progress and staying involved is more important than ever. We remind them again at 90% when the launch is all but imminent.

But ultimately, it's up to those interested in *creating* the site to find support. If you can show even a *moderate* level of support for the site, we'll roust the network audience to help. But the effort *has* to be primarily focused *specifically* on reaching out to experts who will support the site.

At some point (even if it is just once per year) indiscriminately goading a diverse group of users to blanket Area 51 seems a bit spammy and over-reaching.

Answer (score 9):

I say no. Need and inspiration don't come at a pre-ordained time.

Comment: Not unrelated, most proposals are now getting closed as duplicates­. I'd almost advocate shutting it down for a while...

Comment: I realize the apparent contradiction between my answer and the above comment. There's two issues at hand: lack of attention given to Area 51 and duplicate proposals. I'm meditating over what could be done to address each...

Comment: You didn't understand the idea - I am not suggesting we close site creation at other times!

Comment: @Casebash You didn't understand mine: Inspiration for good proposals won't come, even if you have a special week for it. Sure, some in-site publicity would probably bring more people to Area51, but **how would making publicity for a week bring more, better proposals**?

Comment: We already have good proposals, it is just that they don't get enough attention. Extra publicity for a week would give them a chance to get off the ground

Comment: Hmmm, does Area51 have a Twitter account? That would seem relevant.